# Why the time of AWST and CCT are not the same?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have write a static class named"DateUtils" and here is a static method named "parseDate(String)" it will use some patterns to convert the string to a date.
the default timeZone is Asia/Shanghai   (I'am in China)

```
public static final TimeZone SHA = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Shanghai");
```

and it will be passed to the method 
   TimeZone.setDefault(timeZone);
And Using SimpleDateFormat to concert the String.
The matched pattern should be  "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
And Here are three Test of it.

```
//this one is ok.
@Test
public void testParseGMTDate() throws Exception {
    Date date = DateUtils.parseDate("Thu, 02 Aug 2016 08:12:34 GMT");
    assertNotNull(date);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    log.debug(DateUtils.format(cal.getTime()));
    assertEquals(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), 2016);
    assertEquals(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), 8 - 1);
    assertEquals(cal.get(Calendar.DATE), 2);
    assertEquals(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 8 + 8);
    assertEquals(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 12);
    assertEquals(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND), 34);
    assertEquals(DateUtils.format(cal.getTime()), "2016-08-02 16:12:34");
}
// AWST is GMS+8:00 time so this one is ok.
@Test 
public void testParseWSTDate() throws Exception {
    Date date = DateUtils.parseDate("Thu, 02 Aug 2016 08:12:34 AWST");
    assertNotNull(date);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    log.debug(DateUtils.format(cal.getTime()));
    assertEquals(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), 2016);
    assertEquals(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), 8 - 1);
    assertEquals(cal.get(Calendar.DATE), 2);

    assertEquals(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 8);
    assertEquals(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 12);
    assertEquals(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND), 34);
}

// junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 
// Expected :9
// Actual   :8
@Test
public void testParseDateCCT() throws Exception {
    Date date = DateUtils.parseDate("Thu, 02 Aug 2016 08:12:34 CCT");
    assertNotNull(date);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    log.debug(DateUtils.format(cal.getTime()));
    assertEquals(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), 2016);
    assertEquals(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), 8 - 1);
    assertEquals(cal.get(Calendar.DATE), 2);

    assertEquals(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 8); //Expected: 9
    assertEquals(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 12);
    assertEquals(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND), 34);
}
```

And here are some code snippet of DateUtils.

```
public static final TimeZone SHA = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Shanghai");
static {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeZone(SHA);
    calendar.set(2000, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    calendar.set(MILLISECOND, 0);
    TWO_DIGIT_START = calendar.getTime();

}
public static Date parseDate(String dateValue) {
    return parseDate(dateValue, null, null, SHA);
}
public static Date parseDate(String dateValue, String[] dateFormats, Date startDate, TimeZone timeZone) {
        TimeZone.setDefault(timeZone);
        String[] localDateFormats = dateFormats != null ? dateFormats : DEFAULT_PATTERNS;
        Date localStartDate = startDate != null ? startDate : TWO_DIGIT_START;
        String v = dateValue;
        if (dateValue.length() > 1 && dateValue.startsWith("\'") && dateValue.endsWith("\'")) {
            v = dateValue.substring(1, dateValue.length() - 1);
        }

        String[] arr = localDateFormats;
        int len = localDateFormats.length;

        for (String dateFormat : DEFAULT_PATTERNS) {
            //            String dateFormat = arr[i];
            SimpleDateFormat dateParser = DateUtils.DateFormatHolder.formatFor(dateFormat);
            dateParser.set2DigitYearStart(localStartDate);
            ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
            Date result = dateParser.parse(v, pos);
            if (pos.getIndex() != 0) {
                _LOG.debug("Date parsed using: {}", dateFormat);
                return result;
            }
        }

        _LOG.error("Can't parse data: {data:{}, formats:{}, startDate:{},tz:{}}",
                dateValue, localDateFormats, localStartDate, TimeZone.getDefault());
        return null;
    }
```

My Question is:
According to document on the internet, CCT & AWST are both the GMT+8:00 time zone, why in my test it seem like that the CCT Time is GMT+9:00.

Comment: They are? -- [CCT time to AWST time converter](https://www.timejones.com/timezoneconverter/cct-to-awst) -- It seems to me that CCT is `GMT +6:30` and AWST is `GMT +8:00`.

Comment: Very Thanks, There must be some mistake, when i search in baidu.com(a "google" of China) so many documents says CCT is the time for east of China (Beijing Time GMT+8:00)........

Comment: The short Name of China Stand Time should be CST, this is a GMT +8:00. But I still not understand why it is 9 in my code. this will not block my job. I just want to know why.

Comment: `CST` is *also* [`Central Standard Time`](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cst) in North America. One example of why you should never use these 3-4 letter abbreviations. They are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!). Use proper [IANA time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: @zhigangxu Please post clarifications by editing your Answer rather than by posting comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

You have made three mistakes:

- Used non-standard non-unique pseudo-time-zone 3-4 letter abbreviations
- Then proceeded to incorrectly assume their meaning
- Used old outmoded Java classes for date-time handling.

Instead, use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz%20_database_time_zones) in the format of `continent/region`. Study the documented meaning of those zones rather than assume/guess. Use only [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes for date-time work.

All these are common errors made by many programmers, as evidenced by the many Questions here on Stack Overflow.

## Use proper time zone names

`CST` is *also* [`Central Standard Time`](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cst) in North America. One example of why you should never use these 3-4 letter abbreviations. They are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!). Use proper [IANA time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). These are in the format of `continent/region`.

## java.time

You are using old troublesome date-time classes. Avoid them.

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) team also advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

### `Instant`

The `Instant` class is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (GMT) with a resolution up to [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse ( "2016-08-02T08:12:34Z" ); // 02 Aug 2016 08:12:34
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

The `ZonedDateTime` represents an `Instant` adjusted into a time zone.

I assume you meant Australian western standard time by `AWST`, officiall named [`Australia/Perth`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australia/Perth).

```
ZoneId zoneId_Perth = ZoneId.of ( "Australia/Perth" );
ZonedDateTime zdt_Perth = instant.atZone ( zoneId_Perth );
```

For China, you intended [`Asia/Shanghai`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Shanghai).

```
ZoneId zoneId_Shanghai = ZoneId.of ( "Asia/Shanghai" );
ZonedDateTime zdt_Shanghai = zdt_Perth.withZoneSameInstant ( zoneId_Shanghai );
```

I am not sure what your or the old date-time classes meant by `CCT`. [This page](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cct) says it is “Cocos Islands Time”, six and a half hours ahead of UTC year-round (no Daylight Saving Time, DST). Again, this is an example of why you should never use the 3-4 letter abbreviations.

```
ZoneId zoneId_Cocos = ZoneId.of ( "Indian/Cocos" );
ZonedDateTime zdt_Cocos = zdt_Perth.withZoneSameInstant ( zoneId_Cocos );
```

You may have meant [Beijing time](http://time.is/Beijing), according to a comment. If so, know that Beijing time is covered by the [`Asia/Shanghai`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Shanghai) time zone according to [this list in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Dump to console. You can see that both Perth and Shanghai are eight hours ahead of UTC in August this year for an hour-of-day of 16 versus 8 (`16:12:34` versus `08:12:34`). The Cocos Islands is in between, at `14:42:34` for 6.5 hours ahead of UTC.

```
System.out.println ( "instant: " + instant + " | zdt_Perth: " + zdt_Perth + " | zdt_Shanghai: " + zdt_Shanghai + " | zdt_Cocos: " + zdt_Cocos );
```

> instant: 2016-08-02T08:12:34Z | zdt_Perth: 2016-08-02T16:12:34+08:00[Australia/Perth] | zdt_Shanghai: 2016-08-02T16:12:34+08:00[Asia/Shanghai] | zdt_Cocos: 2016-08-02T14:42:34+06:30[Indian/Cocos]

## `DateTimeFormatter`

To generate strings in formats other than the standard ISO 8601 formats shown here, use `DateTimeFormatter` class.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL );
f = f.withLocale( Locale.CHINA );
String output = zdt_Shanghai.format( f );
```